# Question about n-simplex and its face

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I just started to read Elements of Algebraic Topology by Munkres and got question already. On page 5, (Let $\sigma$ be an n-simplex) since Bd $\sigma$ consists of all points $x\in\sigma$ s.t. at least one $t_i(x)=0$, and Int $\sigma$ consists of all pioints $x\in\sigma$ s.t. $t_i(x)>0, \forall i$, it follows:

Given $x\in\sigma$, then there is exactly one face $s$ of $\sigma$ s.t. $x\in$ Int $s$, for $s$ must be the face spanned by those $a_i$ for which $t_i(x)>0$.

My question is, what if $x$ is one of the vertices, say $a_0$. It is not an interior of any faces, so there can't exist a unique face s.t. x contained in the interior of that face. Or am I misunderstood something here. Can someone clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: "Interior" here means the interior with respect to the lowest-dimensional Euclidean space in which the simplex can be embedded. A $2$-simplex can be seen as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ and its interior is then the set of all points $x=\sum_{i=0}^2 t_ia_i$ such that $t_i>0$ for all $i$. A $1$-simplex is basically a unit interval in $\Bbb R$, and the interior is then the open interval with all points $t_0a_0+(1-t_0)a_1$ such that $0<t_0<1$. If you go down to dimension $0$, then the $0$-simplex is the unique point of $\Bbb R^0=\{a_0\}$, and its interior is $\{a_0\}$.

Comment: One sees that the interior of a simplex $\sigma=[a_0,\dots,a_n]$ is precisely the set of those convex combinations $x=\sum_0^n t_i a_i$ such that $t_i>0$ for all $i$. That means for a $0$-simplex, the unique convex combination is $t_0 a_0$ with $t_0=1$, so this point is also in the interior of $[a_0]$.

Comment: @Stefan. Oh, if so then that makes sense. So, the statement is true. I thought the 0-simplex doesn't have interior. Thanks for your explanation, Stefan :)

Comment: @Stefan. Sorry to bother again. Could you copy and paste your comment above to an answer so I can mark my question that it has been solved. Thanks.

Comment: I'll do that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Interior* here means the interior with respect to the lowest-dimensional Euclidean space in which the simplex can be embedded. Technically, the standard-$n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ is the convex hull of the unit vectors $e_0,\dots,e_n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, with the subspace topology. That is 
$$
\textstyle
\Delta^n = \{ (t_0,\dots,t_n) \mid t_i\ge0, \sum_i t_i = 1 \}.
$$
As this set, its interior is empty. However, $\Delta^n$ is also a subset of its affine hull
$$
\textstyle
\text{Aff}(\Delta^n) = \{ (t_0,\dots,t_n) \mid \sum_i t_i = 1 \},
$$
which is a coset of an $n$-dimensional linear subspace of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and thus homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Regarded as a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, $\Delta^n$'s interior is
$$
\textstyle
\mathring\Delta^n = \{ (t_0,\dots,t_n) \mid t_i>0, \sum_i t_i = 1 \}.
$$
That's why we take the interior of a simplex to be the set of all points whose every coordinate is strictly larger than $0$.

If you go down to dimension $0$, then $\Delta^0$ is the subset $\{t_0 \mid t_0=1\}$ of $\Bbb R^1$, and its affine hull is $\Delta^0$ itself, so it is open in there. And this is indeed the set of all elements of the $0$-simplex where every coordinate is $>0$.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. That's a very complete answer! :D

Comment: Hi Stefan, could you also help me about this problem <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735663/intersections-of-a-ray-from-star-domain-to-its-boundary> I think I got my argument false.