# Intersections of a ray from star domain to its boundary

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded, open, star domain (or star-shaped) relative to $x_0$. A ray $R$ from $x_0$ is the set of all points $x_0+tp, p\in\mathbb{R}^n-0, t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.

It is easy to see that if $S$ is convex, then any ray from a point sould intersect Bd $S$ at exactly one point. But, now $S$ is star domain. How could I show that a ray from $x_0$ **may** intersect the boundary at **more** than one point? It is true for the ray not emanating from $x_0$. But if it's the ray emanating from the center, we know that from the definition of star domain, any line segment from $x_0$ to any point in the space is contained in the space, how could be it possible to intersect the boundary in more than two points?

---

Also, from this [Star-shaped domain whose closure is not homeomorphic to $B^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579330/star-shaped-domain-whose-closure-is-not-homeomorphic-to-bn), how can the answer be the topologist's sine curve. That space is connected but not path-connected. While star domain must be path-connected.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your argument that a ray from $x_0$ can intersect $\operatorname{Bd} S$ at  at most one point is correct. However, if $S$ is not bounded, then there exists a ray from $x_0$ which does not intersect $\operatorname{Bd} S$.

Comment: I know that if $S$ is not bounded then there exists a ray from $x_0$ which does not intersect Bd $S$, because star domain is not necessarily bounded. But my argument that a ray from $x_0$ can intersect Bd $S$ at at most one point seems wrong, because the problem is to show that it "may" intersect at more than one point. If $S$ is just convex, it's true.

Comment: @ChenMLing the claim that unbounded star domain has ray that doesn't intersect boundary is false. Consider the union of infinitely many intervals starting at $(0,0)$ to $(n,1)$. If you need it to be open, just take  small open band around each line.

Answer (score 1):

Consider half plane $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ y<0\}$ and let $B$ be the open ball around $(0,0)$ of say radius $1$. Let $X=H\cup B$.

Then $X$ is open, star around $x_0=(0,0)$ but any ray starting from $(a,0)$ through any point of the form $(b,0)$ meets the boundary (which contains most of the X axis) infinitely many times.

Requiring for $X$ to be bounded doesn't change much, I can just take the example above and interesect it with big enough open ball (i.e. around $(0,0)$ of radius $>1$).

---

As for the topologist's sine curve: the answer doesn't claim it is star. It considers the region bounded by the topologist's sine curve.